# Can't mount USB during OpenBSD installation

Tags: mount, usb, system-installation, openbsd, bsd

I'm trying to install OpenBSD and I need to mount USB with wifi firmware, but can't find it inside `/dev`. `sysctl` shows that it is inserted and no errors in `dmesg` about it.

```
$ sysctl hw.disknames
sd0:38df653gdil7fd,rd0:gdr64hrff6gghlo,sd2:

$ dmesg | grep sd2
sd2 at scscibus2 targ 1 lun 0...
sd2: 118272MB, 512 bytes/sector...

$ disklabel sd2
disklabel: /dev/rsd2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What filesystem is the USB?  What have you tried to mount it?

Comment: @MarcWilson exFAT. Before I try I need to know the name corresponding name of block device. There is no candidates in /dev.

Comment: Does `(cd /dev; sh ./MAKEDEV sd2)` create the device for your?